# iOS really check internet connection

Tags: ios, reachability

I have one problem - i need to check really internet connection. What i do now? Now i use **Reachability** class to check if is internet connection, but my app go to crash in this case: I've connected to the wifi in airport, it's was free wi fi but if i am not registred i can't surf. But **Reachability**  thinkin that i've internet connection.How i use **Reachability** now?

```
if(self.internetReachableFoo.isReachable)
{
// We have internet          
}
else
{
//we have no internet
}
```

So my question is, how i can use **Reachability** or other tools to check real internet connection?
thanks.

Comment: Please refrain from using **annoying formatting**.

Comment: Try taking a look at this existing question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083701/how-to-check-for-an-active-internet-connection-on-iphone-sdk?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could attempt to connect to services you know will always be available, such as Google's public DNS servers. A simple ping will suffice.

Comment: can you give me example with ping please ?

Answer (score 2):

I you wan't to check internet connectivity then you can use reachability block

```
Reachability *reachability = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostname:@"www.google.com"];

reachability.reachableBlock = ^(Reachability *reachability) {
    NSLog(@"Network is reachable.");
};

reachability.unreachableBlock = ^(Reachability *reachability) {
    NSLog(@"Network is unreachable.");
};

// Start Monitoring
[reachability startNotifier];
```

Comment: Maybe because the network will let you ping but redirects regular traffic such as that on port 80 and 443 to a proxy. I will add that I don't know how reachability works.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this solution:

```
@implementation SomeClass{

    Reachability* hostReachable;
}
```

Add this to your `viewDidLoad` method

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(checkNetworkStatus:) name:kReachabilityChangedNotification object:nil];

hostReachable = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:@"www.apple.com"];
[hostReachable startNotifier];
```

And this method:

```
-(void) checkNetworkStatus:(NSNotification *)notice

{

    NetworkStatus hostStatus = [self.hostReachable currentReachabilityStatus];
    switch (hostStatus)
    {
        case NotReachable:
        {
            NSLog(@"NotReachable");
            break;
        }
        case ReachableViaWiFi:
        {
            NSLog(@"ReachableViaWiFi");
            break;
        }
        case ReachableViaWWAN:
        {
            NSLog(@"ReachableViaWWAN");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```